# Scrapy delay etiquette

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently working on a project to scrape a Wiki-like website that is a database of historical people and some basic information (all the individual information is on its own page). There are several million (a little under 3 million) names, so I want the crawler to actually completely scrape the information while not hurting the website. I'm completely new to this so I wondered if people could guide me to best practices in web scraping.  Specifically, I've posted a little from the settings file below:

```
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 5
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = True
```

I've uncommented out the AutoThrottle settings and set DOWNLOAD_DELAY to 5 seconds. However, this is going to make the scraper move too slowly. Is this unavoidable if I don't want to get banned? What do people usually set the DOWNLOAD_DELAY parameter to?

Comment: it totally depends on the server you are hitting. That's the thing, you don't know how to crawl a site until you've done it. Another solution would be to contact the site and tell them you want to crawl so they can tell how to do it (most certainly they will forbid it).

Comment: One agent scraping is rather obvious. If you had a cluster of agents you might have a better chance of not getting kicked out. You could fire up a collection of AWS spot instances that all feed a central database.

Comment: @Splatmistro Is there a good guide on how to web scrape with AWS? I just started reading about it

Comment: Not that I know of, here is [a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647844/how-to-automate-amazon-aws-ec2-for-scraping) though.